# java.lang.NoClassDeFfoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, glassfish, java-11

me encuentro realizando una migración de jdk8 a Openjdk11 en eclipse y con Glassfish6. Estoy utilizando Jakarta EE 9 para sustituir las dependencias de javax, pero resulta que cuando intento desplegar la aplicación me sale este error **java.lang.NoClassDeFfoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener** :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Encontré que el código de Apache Commons que usa el paquete javax. * no se compila con el código de Jakarta EE 9 y GlassFish 6 y la carga de archivos comunes depende de javax.servlet y la consola de administración de GlassFish lo usa para cargar implementaciones, entonces que me sugieren para solucionar este Error?